# Setting border-radius in a container whose transform-style: preserve-3d does not work

Tags: css

I was reading a blog post as to CSS-3D. Somewhere it mentions the issue of setting the property `transform-style: preserve-3d` is not working as expected. He did not explain the reason, he just tried the other way to get around the issue. Could you explain why we can not set the property in question in the container?

https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/ZppXbb/

The blog link I was reading:

https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/

Comment: This has nothing to do with either `transform-style` or 3D elements; the problem is that you're setting a `border-radius` on the *parent* of the element with the background, rather than the element itself. If you want to shrink a `background`, the target element (`.face`) needs a `border-radius`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `border-radius` to `face` and it should work just fine.

OR see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/YzrQYgj)

```css
$dim: 40vmin;

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 20em;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: $dim; height: $dim;
}

.face {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.card {
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -.5*$dim;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font: calc(1em + 10vmin)/#{$dim} 
        trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    // shorthand doesn't work in Firefox :(
    // bug 1304014
    font-size: calc(1em + 10vmin);
    line-height: $dim;
    font-family: trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    animation: rot 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rot {
    50% { transform: rotateY(.5turn); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(1turn); }
}

.face {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #ee8c25;
    
    &:last-child {
        transform: rotateY(.5turn);
        background: #d14730;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
    <div class='face'>front</div>
    <div class='face'>back</div>
</div>
```